# Material UI - How to create a 5X4 table with input field and also with row header label and column label

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Eventually the expected result like following:

[image]

I know this one is only 5x3 but I want 5 x 4.

But in my code currently the effect is looks like following.. which is not correct
[image]

And even worst is when I put the value in [0][0] table, all the column 0 will have some value...

Here is my code snippet:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>1st Place</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[0][0]} onChange={handleUmaChange(0, 0)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>2nd Place</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[0][1]} onChange={handleUmaChange(0, 1)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>3rd Place</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[0][2]} onChange={handleUmaChange(0, 2)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>4th Place</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[0][3]} onChange={handleUmaChange(0, 3)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Uma 0 Over</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[1][0]} onChange={handleUmaChange(1, 0)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Uma 1 Over</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[1][1]} onChange={handleUmaChange(1, 1)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Uma 2 Over</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[1][2]} onChange={handleUmaChange(1, 2)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Uma 3 Over</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[1][3]} onChange={handleUmaChange(1, 3)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Uma 4 Over</FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[2][0]} onChange={handleUmaChange(2, 0)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel></FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[2][1]} onChange={handleUmaChange(2, 1)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel></FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[2][2]} onChange={handleUmaChange(2, 2)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel></FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[2][3]} onChange={handleUmaChange(2, 3)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel></FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[3][0]} onChange={handleUmaChange(3, 0)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel></FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[3][1]} onChange={handleUmaChange(3, 1)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel></FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[3][2]} onChange={handleUmaChange(3, 2)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel></FormLabel>
        <TextField variant="outlined" type="number" value={umaValues[3][3]} onChange={handleUmaChange(3, 3)} />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I don't know what I need to change to make the expected result

Comment: What is the expected result? The labels should be in the right right of the input? What does this numbers mean 10, -20, -20 = -20?

Comment: MUI has `Table` component.